In Apache Spark 3.3.2, spark.read.parquet no longer work if the parquet file contains a metadata type of INT64, TIMESTAMP[NANOS]
What the issue:
In a Databricks notebook that attached to a job cluster with DBR: 12.2 LTS (includes Apache Spark 3.3.2, Scala 2.12), I have code as below. It worked before 2024-08-09, but no longer works after that.
spark.read.parquet("dbfs:/path/test.parquet") 

Below is the schema of test.parquet
x: DOUBLE, OPTIONAL
valid_time: INT64, TIMESTAMP[NANOS], OPTIONAL
However, if I excluded metadata of valid_time, the code works. So, it seemed that spark.read.parquet only has problem to read in metadata type of INT64, TIMESTAMP[NANOS].
And I've also tested that pandas can open the same parquet file (metadata includes valid_time), code as below. So it proves the test.parquet is not corrupted.
import pandas as pd
pd.read_parquet('/dbfs/path/test.parquet', engine='fastparquet')

I'm trying to seek for answers of below 2 questions:

Why it's suddenly not working after 2024-08-09
How to resolve the issue? (I prefer not use panda to replace spark.read.parquet to gain the performance benefit)

More investigations that I've done:

I found the same issue in here https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-40819. However, it mentions this issue has been fixed in spark version of 3.3.2 which is the version I'm using now.
I tried to config the spark according to the guide: https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.3.2/configuration.html, but it did not make the spark.read.parquet work either. The code of configuration as below

spark.conf.set("spark.sql.legacy.parquet.int96RebaseModeInRead", "CORRECTED")
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.legacy.parquet.datetimeRebaseModeInRead", "CORRECTED")
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.parquet.int96AsTimestamp", "true")
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.parquet.int96TimestampConversion", "true")
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.parquet.outputTimestampType", "TIMESTAMP_MICROS")
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.parquet.int64AsTimestamp", "true")
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.parquet.int64TimestampConversion", "true")


try spark.sql.legacy.parquet.nanosAsLong=true

Yes, it worked. thanks a lot, Andrew. Just a further question if I could - the configuration of spark.sql.legacy.parquet.nanosAsLong seems not in the spark 3.3.2 document?  https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.3.2/configuration.html. Where could I find the complete list of configurations?

Sorry, I had the same issue you had, and found this by luck in an answer here.
